# Loop through all unchecked Checkboxes (foreach or for-loop, Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, checkbox

I would like to compress the executable code segment (see below). How to do this with a foreach or for-loop?

```
private void UncheckCheckBox() 
{
   CheckBox[] Three = new [] 
   {
     checkBox1,
     checkBox2,
     checkBox3
   };

   checkBox1.Tag = "str1";
   checkBox2.Tag = "str2";
   checkBox3.Tag = "str3";

   if (!checkBox1.Checked) 
   {
     listBox4.Items.Remove(checkBox1.Tag);
   }
   if (!checkBox2.Checked) 
   {
     listBox4.Items.Remove(checkBox2.Tag);
   }
   if (!checkBox3.Checked) 
   {
     listBox4.Items.Remove(checkBox3.Tag);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: Three is not a great variable name. Following normal standards you should start it with a lower case character. Maybe 'checkBoxes' would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without the array. The Controls collection should have your checkboxes:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkBox in Controls.AsQueryable().OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => !c.Checked).ToArray())
    listBox4.Items.Remove(checkBox.Tag);
```

Or using your existing array:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkBox in Three.Where(c => !c.Checked).ToArray())
    listBox4.Items.Remove(checkBox.Tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
foreach(CheckBox cbx in Three)
{
    if(! cbx.Checked)
        listBox4.Items.Remove(cbx.Tag);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. However, thanks for your help!